# Node.js HTTPS configuration error - no common encryption algorithm(s)

Tags: node.js, https, openssl, self-signed, rhel6

I have seen other similar questions but non addresses my problem. I have generated my TLS (openSSL) Self-Signed certificate, but seems not working on my `NodeJS` server.

**Instructions to generate SSL**

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem

openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.pem

openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -export -out certificate.p12

openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -noout -info  // verify certificate
```

So at the end I have `.p12` also known as `PFX` type certificate. Below is my **Node.js** code:

```
    // ------- Start HTTPS configuration ----------------

const options = {

    pfs: fs.readFileSync('./server/security-certificate/certificate.p12'),     
    passphrase: 'secrete2'
};
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443);


    // -------- End HTTPS configuration -----------------

    // Also listen for HTTP 
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('running at localhost: '+port);
});
```

Here is the output when I run `curl` command, the HTTP request is served correctly, only HTTPS has problem:

[image: Output when tested on same machine]

Moreover, if I do this:

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/var/www/html/node_app/server/security-certificate/cert.p12
```

Then I get following error:
`curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`

If I try to access in browser with HTTPS and port, browser says it could not load the page.

> Reference links I followed:
> Node.js HTTPS:
>
> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener
>
> I'm using AWS RedHat Linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478215/how-to-do-https-get-with-client-certificate-in-node

Comment: That is a different thing

Answer (score 0):

So far don't know the solution to the above posted problem related to my `.p12` bundle certificate (used in my `Node.js` configuration).

However I have noticed that when I changed the code and tried to use the `.pem` certificate, it worked correctly with `curl -k <MY-URL>` command.

```
const options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server/security-certificate/cert.pem'),    
    key: fs.readFileSync('./server/security-certificate/key.pem'),      

    //pfs: fs.readFileSync('./server/security-certificate/cert.p12'),   // didn't work

    passphrase: 'secrete'
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443);
```

If any one knows better solution/answer please post that. So far, I'm not sure why `.p12` certificate does not work. Should I rename it to `.pfx` (what is the different and effect)?